# Which is the better stringutils.overlay or concatenation

Tags: java

I want to  know, which is preferable to use StringUtils.overlay or concatenation and why?

```
String b = "txt_{}";
System.out.println(StringUtils.overlay(b, "kkk", 5, 5));

String d = "txt_{" + "kkk" + "}";
System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: Why do you care? Where is StringUtils coming from? Using the + operator is (most often) translated by the compiler to use a StringBuilder; which (most often) represents "best performance" solution anyway. From a "code style" perspective; I would personally prefer the simple appending via "+"; as that code is very easy to understand for everybody; whereas using that method ... requires the reader to know the class and the implementation of "overlay".

Comment: @Jägermeister Actually the `+` operator often isn't the best performance solution, but in practically all of the cases it doesn't matter at all. Code clarity is more important (especially when working with grade school problems like this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a good understanding is best to use a simple add (+). In this case overlay  doesn´t adds nothing useful.
If you are concerned that something may be null use StringUtils.isEmpty(str).

Another option is to use concatenate(Obj[])

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#concatenate%28java.lang.Object[]%29

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#overlay%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: [concatenate](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#concatenate%28java.lang.Object[]%29) is deprecated. We shall use [join](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object[]%29) instead.